# How to only get a certain portion of string?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have this string that I receive from a get request:

---

Rekryteringstest för anställning

---

Det här är rekryteringstestet och samtidigt den sida som är data till programmet som ska skrivas

Uppgiften är ganska generellt skriven för att passa både för de som löser den i t ex Java och de som löser den som t ex en webbsida.

Skriv en lösning som:
 1. Öppnar ett fönster (om inte resultatet visas i t ex webbläsare)
 2. Laddar webbadresser till bilder med tillhörande kommentar (längst ner på den här sidan, nya bilder varje gång sidan laddas!)
 3. Laddar och visar bilderna med tillhörande kommentar
 4. Laddar om data (från den här sidan!) automatiskt var 30:e sekund, vid omladdning kan gamla bilder tas bort
 5. Har en knapp för att manuellt trigga omladdning
 6. Visar någon form av status när data laddas
 7. Har en knapp för att avsluta applikationen
 8. Har en 'Om'-dialog som visar kontaktinformation till dig
 9. Lösningen ska vara enkel att testköra och om applicerbart EN körbar fil

A. Skicka in lösningen inklusive all kod till Bouvet

Hur applikationen ser ut är inte lika viktigt som hur applikationen
 med tillhörande unit-test är skriven och fungerar.

Data: 
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514125067037-8e669dd37638?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=1e2adb26fb5dc49fc14efd7f6aeca128&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80 Mer publik

---------- END OF THE RESPONSE STRING ------------

Every time i make a request, the https link and text after the link updates.

How can I easily get only these values in this big string?

I have tried this

```
    let splittedArray = response.data.split( "Data:" );
```

And then I get this

```
<URL kommentar>
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_gbAWeYsKP4/T899GpY3CSI/AAAAAAAAACw/du8qLqu4xEo/s1600/empty.jpg Lådan
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514125067037-8e669dd37638?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=1e2adb26fb5dc49fc14efd7f6aeca128&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80 Mer publik
```

for example.

From here I would like to split the https links and the text afterwards in different parts so I can easily use them. At the moment I cannot use split because it is an array (the last part)

Comment: "At the moment I cannot use split because it is an array (the last part)" : What prevents you from taking each elements of the array, and apply  split on them ?

Comment: I can take the last part of the array, but from there I want to split each line into its own index. I need to loop through these and put them into img src and p tag for descriptions. A tthe moment it is all inside of onne indexed array

Comment: What do you expect exactly ? I don't see where exactly do you need assistance. It is true using a loop could work. Did you try it ?

Comment: The code to get the last part is the one above let splittedArray = response.data.split("Data:");

My problem is that the last part that I now have is an array with 1 item in it (all of the links etc). However I want it to be 1 item per link etc

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. `let splittedArray = response.data.split( "Data:" );` should give you an array with 2 elements (provided there is only one "Data:" string). The part before the "Data:", and the part after. And in this second part, you have "all the links" (but in your example above, there is only one link, by the way)

Comment: Correct! and the part after "Data:" contains the links. Sometimes there are 2 or more links in the response, so splittedArray[1] can contain 2 or more links. I want it to be like this newArray[0] has 1 link and newArray[1] has the other link

Comment: What you could do : take that last part with all the links. Split this last part by space character `.split(/(\s+)/)` -> this should give you an array of strings. Then you could filter to keep only the strings begining by 'http' .

Comment: I'll try to work a proper answer / example.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but then it told me that splittedArray.split() is not a function

Comment: you have to use split on the string which is the last element of the array, so the second one : `splittedArray[1].split(/(\s+)/)`

Comment: Yes that makes sense! That was my main problem, now I get what I want. Create an answer and i'll mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per clarifications in comments, let's start with an example data here :

```
let splittedArray = [
  "part to be discarded", 
  "<URL kommentar> http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_gbAWeYsKP4/T899GpY3CSI/AAAAAAAAACw/du8qLqu4xEo/s1600/empty.jpg Lådan
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514125067037-8e669dd37638?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=1e2adb26fb5dc49fc14efd7f6aeca128&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80 Mer publik"
];
```

Then, you can't simply use `split` on the variable `splittedArray`.

If you want to do further manipulation on the second part (a string that actually contains the links), you need to get this part by referring it as `splittedArray[1]`.

Then you can probably split it by space characters, and keep the ones starting with 'http'.

```
splittedArray[1].split(/\s+/)
```

```js
let splittedArray = [
  "part to be discarded", 
  "<URL kommentar> http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_gbAWeYsKP4/T899GpY3CSI/AAAAAAAAACw/du8qLqu4xEo/s1600/empty.jpg Lådan \
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514125067037-8e669dd37638?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=1e2adb26fb5dc49fc14efd7f6aeca128&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80 Mer publik"
];

let splittedSecondPart = splittedArray[1].split(/\s+/);

let filteredByHttp = splittedSecondPart.filter(x => x.startsWith('http'));

console.log(filteredByHttp);
```